# Prevent connman from adding a default route for networks without a gateway

Tags: networking, connman

I have a PC running K3OS with two ethernet interfaces. One (eth0) is connected to a network without a DHCP server with a static IP address and the other (eth1) is connected to a network with a DHCP, which returns a default gateway.
K3OS uses connman as its network manager.

I configured two connman services, c and d:

```
/net/connman/service/ethernet_00606561750c_cable
  Type = ethernet
  Security = [  ]
  State = ready
  Favorite = True
  Immutable = False
  AutoConnect = True
  Name = Wired
  Ethernet = [ Method=auto, Interface=eth0, Address=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx, MTU=1500 ]
  IPv4 = [ Method=dhcp, Address=10.4.144.15, Netmask=255.255.255.0, Gateway=10.4.144.254 ]
  IPv4.Configuration = [ Method=dhcp ]
  IPv6 = [  ]
  IPv6.Configuration = [ Method=auto, Privacy=disabled ]
  Nameservers = [ 10.1.1.60 ]
  Nameservers.Configuration = [  ]
  Timeservers = [ 10.1.1.60 ]
  Timeservers.Configuration = [  ]
  Domains = [ domain.com ]
  Domains.Configuration = [  ]
  Proxy = [  ]
  Proxy.Configuration = [  ]
  mDNS = False
  mDNS.Configuration = False
  Provider = [  ]
```

```
/net/connman/service/ethernet_00606561750d_cable
  Type = ethernet
  Security = [  ]
  State = ready
  Favorite = True
  Immutable = False
  AutoConnect = True
  Name = Wired
  Ethernet = [ Method=auto, Interface=eth1, Address=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx, MTU=1500 ]
  IPv4 = [ Method=manual, Address=192.168.10.3, Netmask=255.255.255.0 ]
  IPv4.Configuration = [ Method=manual, Address=192.168.10.3, Netmask=255.255.255.0 ]
  IPv6 = [  ]
  IPv6.Configuration = [ Method=off ]
  Nameservers = [ 8.8.8.8 ]
  Nameservers.Configuration = [  ]
  Timeservers = [  ]
  Timeservers.Configuration = [  ]
  Domains = [  ]
  Domains.Configuration = [  ]
  Proxy = [  ]
  Proxy.Configuration = [  ]
  mDNS = False
  mDNS.Configuration = False
  Provider = [  ]
```

Now what happens, after I reboot the PC or restart the service, I get a default route over eth1 set by connman. But eth1 doesn't feature a Gateway address so all my requests to other networks will fail. My understanding is that connman has an internal ordering of services. The ordering happens by respecting the settings of `PreferredTechnologies` in `/etc/connman/main.config`. When two services of the same technologies are available, it will priotize the one, which was ready the first (Source: [Documentation](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/network/connman/connman/+/1.29/doc/overview-api.txt)). But what I don't understand is, why connman would add a default route for networks without a default gateway. Is there a way to tell connman that a certain service does not feature a default gateway?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution about this?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: I'm checking for nmcli that is wide more ssupported

Answer (score 0):

You can add interfaces that you don't want connman to touch to a blacklist in `/etc/connman/main.conf`:

```
NetworkInterfaceBlacklist=eth1
```

It won't try adding routes through them.